# SD card ddrescue retrieved everything but badblocks lists bad blocks like crazy; how come?

Tags: sd-card, badblocks, ddrescue

It astonishes me that I was able to perfectly recover an SD card with `ddrescue` which was used in an RPi for quite a while. But when I'm scanning the SD card with `badblocks -nvs` bad blocks are listed at a crazy rate. (By the way, before kicking off the rescue operation the RPi was behaving quite erratically.)

Can anybody please explain to me, why `ddrescue` was able to gloriously recover all of the content, and at the same time `badblocks` literally shouts at me, this SD card is broken?

Comment: `badblocks` by definition looks for areas (*blocks*) of the disk that are going bad (*have read errors*); which include areas that are still readable, but not always readable (ie. going bad! or dying shown by the *read errors*).  `ddrescue` however is expected to recover data, thus allows for re-reading sectors (*ignoring read errors*) UNLESS a *defined* `--max-error-count` is reached...  ie. your question makes little sense to me given the very different intentions of those utilities.

Comment: @guiverc My SD card has an enormous amount of bad blocks, i.e. unreadable blocks. Still, `ddrescue` is able to read even the "unreadable" ones it occurs to me. This puzzles me.

Comment: I have a 128 GB SD card and `badblocks -nvs` reports 100% bad blocks.

Comment: `ddrescue` will happily retry until `--max-error-count` is reached as already stated...  `badblocks` is looking for *failing* blocks, thus a read error-count of 1 is bad news in its code as it's a preemptive tool used to detect what maybe failing media.. a much higher 'bar' than used by `ddrescue` which by intention ignores any 'errors' it gets.    Test the card on another device to ensure you don't have a less than ideal card reader etc.  Something is *likely* suspect with the card or your hardware used in reading the card (*down to PSU as good components misbehave on bad power*)

Comment: @guiverc If you make an answer of your comments I'll accept it.

Comment: @guiverc A different card reader yielded the same result - loads of bad blocks.

Comment: If you used a different machine (ie. ruling out any power situation; ie. a *stressed* power supply that is struggling to provide sufficient power/amperage) then your SD card is dying.  Don't forget SD & flash memory is made to cost & has a limited life (esp. write capacity). It's used mostly as relatively *cheap* & *convenient*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`badblocks` looks for areas (*blocks/sectors*) of the disk that are going bad (*have read errors*); which include areas that are still readable (*though may require more than a single read attempt; ie. are going bad/dying*),

`ddrescue` however is expected to recover data, thus allows for re-reading sectors (*ignoring read errors*) UNLESS a defined `--max-error-count` is reached...

ie. the two tools have very different intentions/uses.

`ddrescue` will happily retry until `--max-error-count` is reached as already stated... where as `badblocks` is looking for failing blocks, thus a read error-count of 1 is **bad** news in its code as it's a *preemptive tool* used to detect what maybe failing media.. The preemptive tool having a much higher '*bar*' than used by `ddrescue` which by intention ignores any 'errors' it gets.

Your options are

- test the card on another device to ensure you don't have a less than ideal card reader etc.

Something is likely suspect with the card, **or** your hardware used in reading the card has a problem of some sort (*which could be even PSU, as even good components can misbehave when fed bad power*)